# read an ASCII text file

Tags: zip, ascii

How do I read correctly this ASCII text file?

I can download it as a zip file here: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/eo2016.zip
When I open it out of the zip file, add ".txt" to the file name, and open it in Excel - there are many numbers without any sense displayed (screenshot attached).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsgn2.png)
I have also opened it in MatLab and RStudio, but there these numbers are also displayed.

Anybody knows how to do this correctly?

Comment: `eo2016` consists of 22856 lines, each 9444 characters long. I guess it is a fixed-width file. IRS may be able to tell you more about the format. What kind of _programming-related_ question do you have about the file?

Comment: you are right about the lines and characters. My question would be, how I can read that file in Excel. The IRS has also provided an excel explaining the file data: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/eo2016_derl.xlsx My current attempts always return non-sense numbers as shown in the question's screenshot. The IRS says, a statistical software package is required to read the file, however, also with R or SPSS I receive the non-sense numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the file is in fixed-width format (line length: 9444), and column positions have been specified in [a separate Excel sheet](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/eo2016_derl.xlsx).

Here are 3 possibilities to import such a file in Excel.

## 1. Excel's 'Convert Text to Columns' wizard

There's a 'Text to Columns' button in the 'Data' tab of Excel's ribbon.
It supports fixed-width files, but manually placing 833 column separators will be an incredibly tedious job.
And there seems to be no way to save the column definitions for subsequent imports.

## 2. Use Excel formulas

From the specs sheets (EO990_16), copy columns C and D, and paste them to another Excel sheet, **transposed**; use *Paste Special - Transpose*. This should populate rows 1 and 2 as follows:

```
 1    13    22    26    27   102   162   ...
12     9     4     1    75    60     2   ...
```

Now fill the rest of the sheet starting from row 3 with formulas referencing the data sheet, like you see below.
This is a straightforward duplication of any single cell horizontally and vertically.

```
=MID(Data!$A3, A$1, A$2)    =MID(Data!$A3, B$1, B$2)    =MID(Data!$A3, C$1, C$2)    ...
=MID(Data!$A4, A$1, A$2)    =MID(Data!$A4, B$1, B$2)    =MID(Data!$A4, C$1, C$2)    ...
=MID(Data!$A5, A$1, A$2)    =MID(Data!$A5, B$1, B$2)    =MID(Data!$A5, C$1, C$2)    ...
...                         ...                         ...
```

Source:
https://www.wizardofexcel.com/2011/09/28/saving-a-fixed-width-import-layout/

## 3. Convert to CSV

CSV is easy to import.
This command-line approach may help:
[convert a fixed width file from text to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561786/convert-a-fixed-width-file-from-text-to-csv)

Comment: Hey Ruud, Thank you! That was the solution! I actually did almost exactly like that. So, the "statistical software package" proposed by the IRS wasnt required, Excel did it.

Comment: @Georg I'm curious, which of the options did you use? It may be useful for others to learn which one(s) actually worked in practice. And if you found my answer useful, then please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I used Excel, just separating the data with formulas according to the length of each cell described in the explanation excel.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a text document why don't you open it in a text editor?

Comment: This is not an answer. Regardless of whether or not you have the reputation to comment.